# Enums/Documentation with LESS Mixins

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I am creating a set of LESS mixins with Visual Studio/Web Essentials.

Is it possible to write XML-type documentation for LESS mixins?  Or perhaps have an enum to limit the parameters that are input?

For instance, with this mixin:

```
.background-clip(@value)
{
    -webkit-background-clip: @value;
       -moz-background-clip: @value;
            background-clip: @value;
}
```

It would be nice to have some documentation that describes the three possible values, just like when you are creating a normal CSS selector for background-clip -

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### An "Enum" List of Accepted Values

This would be handled through a parametric mixin call, like this:

```
.background-clip(@value) when (@value = border-box),
                              (@value = padding-box),
                              (@value = content-box),
                              (@value = inherit)
{
    -webkit-background-clip: @value;
       -moz-background-clip: @value;
            background-clip: @value;
}
```

This only allows the four values given to be passed in order for it to activate. So this:

```
.test1 {
  .background-clip(border-box);
}

.test2 {
  .background-clip(something);
}
```

Would yield this output (ignoring the second call because it is not valid):

```
.test1 {
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  -moz-background-clip: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
}
```

### Commented Feedback

If feedback to the user was wanted, then a second parametric mixin could offer that through a comment.

**OPTION 1** is pure comment

```
.background-clip(@value) when not (@value = border-box) and
                              not (@value = padding-box) and
                              not (@value = content-box) and
                              not (@value = inherit)
{
  /* WARNING - INVALID INPUT
     CSS output for backbround-clip property given in
     LESS .background-clip() call has been suppressed
     due to invalid input.

     VALID INPUT is one of:
       border-box
       padding-box
       content-box
       inherit
  */
}
```

Then the above test case would have this additional output:

```
.test2 {
  /* WARNING - INVALID INPUT
     CSS output for backbround-clip property given in
     LESS .background-clip() call has been suppressed
     due to invalid input.

     VALID INPUT is one of:
       border-box
       padding-box
       content-box
       inherit
  */
}
```

**OPTION 2** includes a bogus property value to show what the improper `@value` input was:

```
.background-clip(@value) when not (@value = border-box) and
                              not (@value = padding-box) and
                              not (@value = content-box) and
                              not (@value = inherit)
{
  /* WARNING - INVALID INPUT */
  invalid-background-clip-input-equals: @value;
  /* CSS output for backbround-clip property given in
     LESS .background-clip() call has been suppressed
     due to invalid input.

     VALID INPUT is one of:
       border-box
       padding-box
       content-box
       inherit
  */
}
```

Which outputs this additional test case CSS:

```
.test2 {
  /* WARNING - INVALID INPUT */
  invalid-background-clip-input-equals: something;
  /* CSS output for backbround-clip property given in
         LESS .background-clip() call has been suppressed
         due to invalid input.

         VALID INPUT is one of:
           border-box
           padding-box
           content-box
           inherit
      */
}
```

Browsers would ignore the unrecognized "property" of `invalid-background-clip-input-equals`, but it would alert one viewing the compiled css what invalid the value passed was.

**OPTION 3** includes a bogus (i.e. undefined) mixin to potentially force a compilation error (different compilers might handle undefined mixins differently):

```
.background-clip(@value) when not (@value = border-box) and
                              not (@value = padding-box) and
                              not (@value = content-box) and
                              not (@value = inherit)
{
   .background-clip-undefined();
}
```

Which outputs in [this compiler](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.background-clip(%40value)%20when%20(%40value%20%3D%20border-box)%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%40value%20%3D%20padding-box)%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%40value%20%3D%20content-box)%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%40value%20%3D%20inherit)%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20-webkit-background-clip%3A%20%40value%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-moz-background-clip%3A%20%40value%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background-clip%3A%20%40value%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.background-clip(%40value)%20when%20not%20(%40value%20%3D%20border-box)%20and%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20not%20(%40value%20%3D%20padding-box)%20and%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20not%20(%40value%20%3D%20content-box)%20and%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20not%20(%40value%20%3D%20inherit)%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20%20.background-clip-undefined()%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.test1%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.background-clip(border-box)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.test2%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.background-clip(something)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D) this information:

```
SyntaxError: .background-clip-undefined is undefined on line 24, column 3:

23 .test2 {
24   .background-clip(something);
25 }
```

This may be a way to "force" the less programmer to input a valid value by throwing an error. Note how in this case the actual undefined mixin giving the error is the `.background-clip-undefined()`, yet this compiler is actually providing the "calling" information `.background-clip(something)` which is really what the error is.

One could combine options 2 and 3 so that if an error is not thrown by a compiler, at least the comment feedback is visible.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for such a great response!

Comment: ScottS this is a nice answer but would it be possible to make the less compilation fail instead of ignoring the bad mixin usage???

Comment: @SebastienLorber: Updated with an Option 3 that may work to do what you requested (though it may vary by compiler what the effect would be and what information would be returned).

Comment: ScottS that is probably working :) however this is a bit hacky and needs too much boilerplate by creating `when not` clauses to be useful to me. I've created this issue and will probably create a less plugin soon: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2747#issuecomment-161789791